# How to Create index on text and int columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am using a postgresql table where it is joined on two columns (name, id)  Example,

```
SELECT * FROM employee_project ep
INNER JOIN employee_shareable es 
ON ep.project_name = es.project_name AND ep.empployee_id = es.emp_id
```

Here, employee_shareable table is already having indexes like

For project_name,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_project_name ON public.employee_shareable 
    USING btree (project_name)
CREATE INDEX idx_vector_project_name ON public.employee_shareable 
    USING gin (to_tsvector(project_name))
```

For emp_id,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_emp_id ON public.employee_shareable 
    USING btree (emp_id)
```

Is this enough or do we need to add index for both like,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_emp_shareable ON public.employee_shareable 
    USING btree (project_name, emp_id)
```

Comment: Unless both tables are large enough to warrant a merge join, PostgreSQL will probably perform a hash join, and no index can speed that up.

Comment: Why would you join and `id` *and* `name`? The ID should be unique and do the job on its own. (In a normalized design, the redundant `employee_shareable.emp_name` shouldn't even exist.)

Comment: Sorry, my example was not opt. Now I have updated it. The employee ID will be unique but project name will be multiple.